# gwt tooltip with a delay

Tags: gwt

I need to implement a tooltip with a time delay, say, when user point to a widget, the tooltip popup 2 seconds later. i tried the timer but then it shows again and again, i guess that's because the timer fire the tooltip every VISIBLE_DELAY seconds. is there anyway i can fire it only once?  or is there any Class that can sleep for 2 seconds then i can call tooltip.show()? Thanks.

```
    removeDelay = new Timer() {
       @Override
        public void run() {

            ToolTip.this.show();
        }
    };
    removeDelay.schedule(VISIBLE_DELAY);
```

Comment: The code as you've written it should work. Calling `schedule()` makes it happen once, in N seconds, and `scheduleRepeating()` would make it happen repeatedly every N seconds. Do you have code that's creating the Timer more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call cancel after you show the tooltip.

```
new Timer() {
       @Override
        public void run() {

            ToolTip.this.show();
            cancel();
        }
    };
```